# 2.8 - Edge loop with 3 edges?

Tags: modeling

new to blender but not to 3D modelling (a LOT of lightwave) I'm trying to create a face grid between 3 connected edges formin a loop.
I tried with the standard loop and bridge and loop tools addon but each time the grid is only following 2 edges out of 3...(see attached screenshots)

I know how to do it in lightwave with splines but I'm stuck in blender.
[image: edges selected]

[image: the result with the edge not followed visible]

[Edit 14/05] I tried the bsurfaces addon. And the only result I could have is an error message...

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: See https://blenderartists.org/t/bsurfaces-v1-5/513717

Comment: Not sure how could Bsurfaces help here, if taking first screenshot and trying to get filled surface I'd use Grid Fill. If that surface should be flat using curves could be an option, e.g circle curve set to 2D mode.

Comment: I just tried grid fill and blender is either asking for not more than 2 edges or edges not connected...

Comment: 2 possible reasons - edges not connected (but overalpping) or uneven amount of vertices (e.g 17 instead of 16). Not much to add without the file. If you want anyone to check it upload it on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: The edges are connected for sure, they share the same vertices. I think too that it's only a matter of vertices selction but my main issue is that the grid fill works great with 4 sides "holes". Here I have 3 or only two. Anyway, thanks for your help, I will upload the file tonight (currently working)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos unfortunately Bsurfaces is quite broken.. it would be great to bring it back to life.. I don't think I'm quite ready yet....